# Adding minutes to DATETIME

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add a certain number of minutes to the current time in an SQL table. For this purpose, I tried the DATEADD SQL function:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO Waiting_list(
    ID_Patient, 
    Arrival_Time, 
    Classification, 
    Target_Time)
VALUES (
    "'.$_SESSION['id'].'", 
    NOW(), 
    "'.$_SESSION['classification'].'", 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, @'.$waitingtime.', @NOW()))';
```

The column Target_Time has the type `DATETIME`.
Although, I am getting an SQL error near '())'. Doesn't `NOW()` work with `DATEADD`?

Comment: which database system?

Comment: since you tagged the question in php, may I ask why don't you compute date/time in php and then insert it to whatever database you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL you should use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```sql
date_add(now(), interval waitingtime MINUTE)
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41bcd/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It kinda looks like you may be using SQL-SERVER?  in that case, try this:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO Waiting_list(
ID_Patient, 
Arrival_Time, 
Classification, 
Target_Time)
VALUES (
"'.$_SESSION['id'].'", 
getdate(), 
"'.$_SESSION['classification'].'", 
DATEADD(MINUTE, @'.$waitingtime.', getdate()))';
```